# Dealing with WordPress Custom Walker

Tags: wordpress

Let me try to explain the problem again.I'm making megaMenu for my custom theme and I made two walker, first for getting some custom options in dashboard menus i-e: Select The Number of Columns and the code for that is below and working correct for me.

```
/** Mega Menu Columns */

 <p class="field-megamenu-columns description description-wide">
            <label for="edit-menu-item-megamenu-columns-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                <?php _e( 'Mega Menu Number of Columns'); ?>
                <select id="edit-menu-item-megamenu-columns-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-megamenu-columns" name="menu-item-megamenu-columns[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]">
                    <option value="auto" <?php selected( $item->megamenu_columns, 'auto' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Auto'); ?></option>
                    <option value="1" <?php selected( $item->megamenu_columns, '1' ); ?>>1</option>
                    <option value="2" <?php selected( $item->megamenu_columns, '2' ); ?>>2</option>
                    <option value="3" <?php selected( $item->megamenu_columns, '3' ); ?>>3</option>
                    <option value="4" <?php selected( $item->megamenu_columns, '4' ); ?>>4</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </p>

        <?php 

        /** Mega Menu Columns End */?>
```

Then I saved and Update it like below...

```
function custom_nav_update($menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {


 if ( is_array($_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu-columns']) ) {
        $custom_value_megaMenu_columns = $_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu-columns'][$menu_item_db_id];
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu-item-megamenu-columns', $custom_value_megaMenu_columns );
    }

}



add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','custom_nav_item' );

function custom_nav_item($menu_item) {

    $menu_item->megamenu_columns = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu-item-megamenu-columns', true );


    return $menu_item;
}

add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'custom_nav_edit_walker',10,2 );
```

**NOW WITH ABOVE CODE MY DASHBOARD MENU SECTION IS COMPLETED AND RUNNING WITH NO PROBLEM**

Time to retrieve this value on client end is the main problem and the walker I write for that contains the following code to retrieve this value...

```
public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;


        if( $depth === 0 ) {
        $this->megamenu_columns = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu-item-megamenu-columns', true );
        }


    if($depth === 1) {
        $classes[] = 'qcr_sub_menu_'.$allowed_columns;
    }
```

and in here I got $allowed_columns = **Blank**
*I hope all this helps to understand the real problem.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand completely your problem. So here is my idea and code.
The idea is about. At level one save all classes, At level two get it out.

Try this:

```
    if($depth === 0) {
        update_post_meta($menu_item->ID, '_menu-item-levelOne_something', $allowed_columns);
    }

    if($depth === 1) {
        $allowed_columns = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu-item-levelOne_something', true );
        $classes[] = 'qcr_sub_menu_'.$allowed_columns;
    }
```

Comment: **At level one save all classes, At level two get it out.**
Thats What I gotta do... and the code above is not working for me. First if is not working and in the end I got the blank $allowed_columns :/

Comment: I updated my problem please take a look may be it makes sense now. Appreciate you answer.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply but I am stuff. because all complex code you give to me and finally I realize "change $allowed_columns to $this->megamenu_columns. Ok my bad. I am thinking too complicated

Comment: Its alright Bro... That's the right answer but I figured that out earlier this day but appreciate your concern.Thanks again.